# Item generation system in Unity - How to retain scriptable object editing capability after script instanciation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, decorator, wrapper

I am currently working on a game, and I have been running into issues with my design. Namely my items and abilities systems.

I started by using inheritance to add functionalities to my items, say by having an `Item` base class and having both `ConsumableItem` and `Equipment` inheriting inheriting from it. But then I started wanting items that where both consumable and equipment (say a set of arrows). Because I use Unity 3D and C# I cannot inherit from multiple classes, plus I read it can lead to problems down the line.

I heard about interfaces, which could be a solution to my problem, but would still require me to hard code every single combination of attributes by hand.

I started reading about design patterns and was wondering if I could use a decorator pattern to combine attributes and methods to make custom objects in the editor.

I am hoping for the possibility to create a base `ItemBlueprint` class that would take an array of functionalities as `enum` values. I would then pass that `ItemBlueprint` object to another class that would have a method called `Build` and would build the item by adding all the relevant attributes and methods to an `Item` object. The output product could then be added to the scene on a gameobject as a component or saved directly to the assets as a scriptableObject. I would then be able to edit public fields manually.

So far I have been able to generate the item using the code below. However the only field displayed in the unity inspector is that of the attributes corresponding to the last applied decorator. Therefore, I cannot modify the `description` when it consumable is set as the last entry in the blueprint characteritics array, but not the `equipmentSlot` attribute.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ItemBuilder : MonoBehaviour {
    public ItemBluePrint bp;

    private List<Decorator> items;

    public void OnValidate()
    {
        items = new List<Decorator>();
    }

    [ContextMenu("Build Item")]
    public void Build ()
    {
        // Create Item and Decorators
        DiscreteItem newItem = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<DiscreteItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < bp.properties.Length; i++) {
            if (i == (int) ItemProperties.Consumable) {
                items.Add(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<ConsumableItem>());
            }
            if (i == (int) ItemProperties.Equipable) {
                items.Add(ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<EquipableItem>());
            }
        }

        // Link decorators
        Item previousItem = (Item) newItem;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {
            items [i].SetItem (previousItem);
            previousItem = (Item) items [i];
        }

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset (previousItem, "Assets/MynewItem.asset");
        Debug.Log ("Item created !");
    }

    abstract class Item : ScriptableObject
    {
        public abstract void Operation();
    }

    class DiscreteItem : Item
    {
        public override void Operation()
        {
            Debug.Log("Use item.");
        }
    }

    abstract class Decorator : Item
    {
        protected Item item;

        public void SetItem(Item item)
        {
            this.item = item;
        }

        public override void Operation()
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                item.Operation();
            }
        }
    }

    class ConsumableItem : Decorator
    {
        public string description;

        public override void Operation()
        {
            base.Operation();
            Debug.Log("I consume the item.");
        }
    }

    class EquipableItem : Decorator
    {
        public int equipementSlot;

        public override void Operation()
        {
            base.Operation();
            AddedBehavior();
            Debug.Log("I equip the item.");
        }

        void AddedBehavior()
        {
            Debug.Log("I added the item to my equipment.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the blueprint class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public enum ItemProperties
{
    Consumable = 0,
    Equipable = 1,
}

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName= "Item", menuName="Item")]
public class ItemBluePrint : ScriptableObject {
    public ItemProperties[] properties;
}
```

Comment: You should: give a real world example on how you'd like to use it, and the problems you are encountering. (your question title does not reflect the content)

Comment: This is actually what I am looking to achieve, except I have got much more characteristics than just consumable and equipable. I will edit the title.

Comment: You're talking about editing in the title but nowhere in the question, in the inspector you mean ??

Comment: Yes, the created scriptableobject from the `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` call is not editable in the Unity editor.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think you actually need to call `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` on the object you created with `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance`. You call it on an object that you set to that, but didn't create the same way.

Comment: So I just needed to add an extension `.asset` to the name, now the attributes from the last decorator to be applied are visible. But not the ones from the previous decorators.

Comment: This is why Interfaces are awesome.

Comment: Hello Draco18s, could you elaborate a bit more ? If I used interfaces wouldn't I have to copy past the same `Equip` or `Consume` method in every single item class I want to have in the game, that I want to implement Consumable and Equipment? That seems redundant and cumbersome, I am trying to use the Unity Editor UI as much as I can.

Comment: Well, you would combine inheritance and interfaces. You'd have some base class and somewhere along the path you will have something like `public class Consumable : ParentClass, IConsumable` which is the parent class for each consumable item you have. Yes, you might need to implement an interface more than once if some classes are not at the same path of the tree (so to speak), but on the other hand you will be able to reduce overlapping to just the stuff the interface does.